# When can $ x = \bigcup \mathscr{P}(x)$ become $ x = \mathscr{P}(\bigcup x)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When can $ x = \bigcup \mathscr{P}(x)$ become $ x = \mathscr{P}(\bigcup x)$ where $\mathscr{P}$ is the power set? I know the first is true by checking $\subseteq $ and $\supseteq$, however I'm not quite sure when the second part is true?
Can anyone give any examples

Comment: Latex tip: use \mathscr to write the powerset $\mathscr P$

Comment: I think that the second equality isn't true as for any set the empty set is in its power set,  but it does not have to be an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Sassatelli Giulio for giving some guidance.

Suppose there is some $y$ such that $x= \mathscr{P} \left(y\right)$, then, using the $x= \bigcup \mathscr {P} \left(x\right) $ equality, $$\bigcup x= \bigcup \mathscr{P} \left(y\right) = y$$
Therefore, $x= \mathscr{P} \left(\bigcup x\right)$.

Suppose $x= \mathscr{P} \left(\bigcup x\right)$, take $y=\bigcup x$. So there is one $y$ with $x = \mathscr{P} \left(y\right)$.

Therefore, $x= \mathscr{P} \left(\bigcup x\right)$ if and only if there is some $y$ such that $x = \mathscr{P} \left(y\right)$.

Some examples:
$$\{ \emptyset \} = \mathscr{P} \left(\emptyset\right) = \mathscr{P} \left(\bigcup \{ \emptyset \}\right) $$
$$\{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \} = \mathscr {P} \left(\{\emptyset \}\right) = \mathscr {P} \left(\bigcup \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset \} \}\right) $$

Comment: But $\mathscr{P}(\phi) = \{ \phi \} \neq \phi$

Comment: True, but $\{\emptyset \} = \mathscr{P} (\emptyset) = \mathscr{P} (\bigcup \{ \emptyset \})$.